# Angular: Member <function-name> is not callable

Tags: angular

I'm assigning an imported function to a component property in the `constructor` in order to use it in the `template`.

Builds happen properly, but in my editor (Visual Studio Code with Angular Language Service), the below error is shown.

[image: Error]

Below is the code of my exported function.

```
export function downloadFile(fileUrl: string, fileName: string) {
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = fileUrl;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
}
```

Below is my code in the component.

```
import { downloadFile } from '../../shared/utilities';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class SomeComponent {
    downloadFile: any;

    constructor() {
        this.downloadFile = downloadFile;
    }
}
```

I can't get why this error is shown. Please help!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think instead of declaring your download file this way in your component file

`downloadFile: any;`

You should declare it this way

`downloadFile: () => any;`

check this out if it helps.

Comment: Oddly enough, "downloadFile: any;" works for me, while "downloadFile: () => any;" doesn't.

Answer (score 15):

Just in case it will help someone, I had the same problem and the answer above wasn't even close to the solution. After some attempt, I found out it was caused by a name conflict. I had a template variable with the same name as a method. Angular was trying to invoke the template variable, and it ended up showing that error message.
For example:

```
// template
<form #foo (ngSubmit)="foo()">

// TypeScript
foo() {
...
}
```

It says:

> [Angular] member `foo` is not callable